# How can I compute the area of intersection of two polygons with sympy?

Tags: python-3.x, polygon, sympy

How can I compute the area of intersection of two polygons with sympy?

Given are two polygons in sympy (sympy.geometry.polygon.Polygon)

I'm new to python and sympy, so I don't have any code to show.
I tried learning it from documentation but I'm confused at the moment.

Can someone help?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It might not be what you'd like to hear, but you'll have to give a try first. Try writing the code from the references you come across, and if you face a specific problem with that piece of code, you can post it here.

Comment: @PraveenRai Okey, I will try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SymPy will calculate intersections of lines and points but does not calculate regions of overlap. I would recommend looking [elsewhere](https://pypi.org/project/pyclipper/).

Comment: Can you show me, where can I find a good documentation for pyclipper or some tutorilas?

Comment: I don't use the package myself.

Answer (score 0):

I modified the [source code](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/26f7bdbe3f860e7b4492e102edec2d6b429b5aaf/sympy/geometry/polygon.py#L892-L946) to make a function that also includes points inside the other polygon:

```py
def polygon_intersection(p1: sympy.Polygon, p2: sympy.Polygon) -> sympy.Polygon:
    intersection_result = []
    
    assert isinstance(p1, sympy.Polygon)
    assert isinstance(p2, sympy.Polygon)
    
    k = p2.sides
    for side in p1.sides:
        if p2.encloses_point(side.p1):
            intersection_result.append(side.p1)
        if p2.encloses_point(side.p2):
            intersection_result.append(side.p2)
        for side1 in k:
            if p1.encloses_point(side1.p1):
                intersection_result.append(side1.p1)
            if p1.encloses_point(side1.p2):
                intersection_result.append(side1.p2)
            for res in side.intersection(side1):
                if isinstance(res, sympy.Segment):
                    intersection_result.extend(res.points)
                else:
                    intersection_result.append(res)
            

    intersection_result = list(sympy.utilities.iterables.uniq(intersection_result))

    if intersection_result:
        return sympy.Polygon(*intersection_result)
    else:
        return None
```

You can then calculate the area using `polygon_intersection(p1, p2).area`

Comment: In SymPy, the area is signed so unless the order of points is preserved, the area might not  be what you expect. But if you wrap the output in `convex_hull` it will resolve the ordering. You can test with `Triangle((0,0),(0,1),(2,0))` and `Triangle((1,Rational(1,10)),(2,3),(3,-1))` whose intersection should have area of `813/3740`.

Comment: But this isn't going to work well if a concave portion of a polygon is inside of another polygon.